# Insert before Table enters text at the start of document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a piece of code that inserts various tables into word from excel, I am trying to set a start and end text for each table however the start text all ends at the start of the document. 
I dont really use VBA in my day to day so i am unsure how i need to edit this to enter above each table individually.

```
Dim objword
Dim objdoc
Dim Selection As Excel.Range
Dim WordTable


'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Create Word Doc with Thin Margins
    Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objdoc = objword.Documents.Add
objword.Visible = True
objdoc.PageSetup.TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
objdoc.PageSetup.BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
objdoc.PageSetup.LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
objdoc.PageSetup.RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    objword.Activate


'Transactions
 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Transactions")) >= 1 Then

Set Selection = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TF_Flags").ListObjects("Transactions").Range
   Selection.Copy

'Paste Table into MS Word
objdoc.Paragraphs.Add
objdoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteExcelTable _
  LinkedToExcel:=False, _
  WordFormatting:=False, _
  RTF:=False

'enter start and end lines for table
objdoc.Content.InsertBefore Text:=" Transactions start."
 objdoc.Content.InsertAfter Text:=" Transactions end."

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
objword.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (2)

'add small delay
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

   End If

'Notes
 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Notes")) >= 1 Then

Set Selection = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TF_Flags").ListObjects("Notes").Range
   Selection.Copy

 'Paste Table into MS Word
objdoc.Paragraphs.Add

objdoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteExcelTable _
  LinkedToExcel:=False, _
  WordFormatting:=False, _
  RTF:=False

'enter start and end lines for table
 objdoc.Content.InsertBefore Text:=" Notes start."
 objdoc.Content.InsertAfter Text:=" Notes end."


'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
objword.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (2)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your start texts are all at the start of the document because you have used `objdoc.Content.InsertBefore`. `objdoc.Content` is a `range` that represents the entire content of the document.

It would make things simpler for you if you change the order in which you add things. As you evidently know what text needs to precede/follow each table make your insertions in that order, i.e.

1. Insert the preceding text
2. Paste in your table
3. Insert the following text

As you will see from the code below adding content as you go keeps things simpler.

NOTES:

When you paste your table into in Word it will automatically be followed by a new para so there is no need to add a new para for the table's end text.

I have added an additional empty para between the end text of the first table and the start text of the second. Just delete that line if you don't need it.

```
  'Transactions
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Transactions")) >= 1 Then

    Set Selection = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TF_Flags").ListObjects("Transactions").Range
    Selection.Copy

    'enter start line for table and add new para for table
    objdoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = " Transactions start."
    objdoc.Paragraphs.Add
    'Paste Table into MS Word
    objdoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteExcelTable _
      LinkedToExcel:=False, _
      WordFormatting:=False, _
      RTF:=False

    'enter end line for table
    objdoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = " Transactions end."

    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
    objword.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (2)

    'add small delay
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

  End If

  'Notes
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Notes")) >= 1 Then

    Set Selection = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TF_Flags").ListObjects("Notes").Range
    Selection.Copy
    'add an empty para as a separator
    objdoc.Paragraphs.Add
    'add another para and enter start line for table
    objdoc.Paragraphs.Add
    objdoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = " Notes start."
    'Paste Table into MS Word
    objdoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.PasteExcelTable _
      LinkedToExcel:=False, _
      WordFormatting:=False, _
      RTF:=False

    'enter end line for table
    objdoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text = " Notes end."

    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
    objword.ActiveDocument.Tables(2).AutoFitBehavior (2)

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    'Clear The Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

  End If
```